# Verify the hyperbolic integration formula

Tags: calculus, integration, hyperbolic-functions

Verify the integration formula:

$$\int \operatorname{sech} x \, dx =\sin^{-1}(\tanh x)+C$$

I know that I have to manipulate the equation, but I am not sure how. Here is what I have done so far:

\begin{align}
& \int \operatorname{sech} x \, dx \\[6pt]
= {} & \int{\operatorname{sech}^3x\over \operatorname{sech}^2 x} dx \\[6pt]
= {} & \int{\operatorname{sech}^3x\over 1-\operatorname{tanh}^2x} \,dx
\end{align}

$$u= \operatorname{tanh} x, \quad du= \operatorname{sech}^2x \, dx$$

I am not even sure if I am even doing anything right up to this point. If someone could steer me in the right direction that would be great.

Comment: Why don't you just take a derivative?

Comment: Oh, you mean starting from $sin^{-1}(tanhx)+C$ and taking the derivative of that?

Comment: Yes, you only have to verify what the anti-derivative is, so usually there is no reason to evaluate the anti-derivative if you already know what it equals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\sech}{\operatorname{sech}}\newcommand{\tanh}{\operatorname{tanh}}$To verify, Take the derivative of both sides of the equation:
$$\int \sech(x)\,dx=\arcsin(\tanh(x)) + c$$
$$\sech(x)=\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} x}[\arcsin(\tanh(x)) + c]$$
$\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} x}[\arcsin(u)]=\frac{u'}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}$ and $\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} x}[\tanh(x)]=\sech^2(x)$
$$\sech(x)=\frac{\sech^2(x)}{\sqrt{1-\tanh^2(x)}}$$
$1-\tanh^2(x)=\sech^2(x)$
$$\sech(x)=\frac{\sech^2(x)}{\sqrt{\sech^2(x)}}$$
$$\sech(x)=\sech(x)$$

Comment: I've up-voted this but I also find a fault in it: It should be organized like this: $$ \frac{\mathrm{d}} {\mathrm{d}x} (\arcsin\operatorname{tanh} x) = \frac{\operatorname{sech}^2 x}{\sqrt{1 - \operatorname{tanh}^2 x}} = \frac{\operatorname{\sech}^2  x}{\sqrt{\operatorname{sech}^2 x}} = \operatorname{sech} x  $$ i.e. "equals" signs should appear only between things that are ALREADY KNOWN to be equal rather than between things you want to prove are equal. $\qquad$

Comment: Thank you for the feedback; I will take it into consideration when answering questions in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Use the definition of the hyperbolic secant:

$$\int\text{sech}(x)\ \text{d}x = \int\frac{1}{\cosh(x)}\ \text{d}x = \int\frac{2}{e^x + e^{-x}}\ \text{d}x$$

Let's collect an $e^x$ term

$$\int\frac{2e^{-x}}{1 + e^{-2x}}\ \text{d}x$$

We can now use the Geometric Series for the term $\frac{1}{1 + e^{-2x}}$

$$\int 2e^{-x}\sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty}(-e^{-2x})^k = \sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty}2(-1)^k\int e^{-x}e^{-2kx}\ \text{d}x = \sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty}2(-1)^k\int e^{-x(1 + 2k)}\ \text{d}x$$

Integration is trivial and you end up with

$$\sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty}2(-1)^k \frac{-1}{1 + 2k}e^{-x(1+2k)} = \sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty} \frac{2\cdot (-1)^{k+1}}{1+2k}e^{-x(1+2k)}$$

This is a well known series and it's

$$\sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty} \frac{2\cdot (-1)^{k+1}}{1+2k}e^{-x(1+2k)} = -2\arctan(e^{-x}) = -2\operatorname{arccot}(e^x)$$

Comment: This answer starts out well but then I think it gets too complicated. How about this:
$$
\int\operatorname{sech}(x)\, dx = \int \frac 1 {\cosh(x)}\, dx = \int\frac 2 {e^x + e^{-x}}\, dx = \int \frac {2e^x\, dx} {e^{2x} + 1} = \int \frac{2\,du}{u^2+1}
$$
$$
= 2\arctan u + C = 2\arctan(e^x) + C.
$$
(However, given the way the question is phrased, I would answer it just by finding $\dfrac d {dx} \sin^{-1}( \operatorname{tanh} x).$) $\qquad$

Comment: A typesetting issue: when you write 2\text{arccot}(e^x) instead of 2\operatorname{arccot}(e^x) then you don't get the proper amount of space between $2$ and $\operatorname{arccot}$.  Thus: $$ 2\text{arccot}(e^x) \qquad \text{versus} \qquad 2\operatorname{arccot}(e^x) $$ I edited the answer accordingly. $\qquad$

Comment: Thank you Sir! Well done! Thank you!

Comment: @MichaelHardy Great answer, you definitely made things lots easier!

Answer (score 1):

A slightly unconventional procedure is to force hyperbolic functions to the circular

ones by $ x\rightarrow ix $ on either side of the equation.

$$\text{LHS}= \int \operatorname{sech} ix \, d ix = i \int \sec x \, dx = i \log ( \sec x + \tan x) $$

$$\text{RHS}= \sin^{-1}(\operatorname{tanh} ix)+C = i \operatorname{sinh}^{-1}(\tan x)  = i \log( \sec x + \tan x) $$

Comment: Your typesetting was horrible.  I cleaned it up.